# Making other elements scroll with the ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview

I am aware that I am not supposed to use ScrollView as a parent to a ListView.

However, I want to scroll the ListView along with the ImageView on top of it. Please guide me how should I do it. Thanks.

```
<ImageView/>
<ListView/>
```

The ImageView scroll as if its a part of the listView... also, my ListView has a text + image.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your ListView adapter return the ImageView as the renderer for item zero in the list?

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to have the image appear at the top of the list and scroll away as the ListView scrolls, then you should use [`ListView.addHeaderView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) and pass it the ImageView. Make sure to call this before calling setAdapter() on your ListView.

Comment: Okay, so do you mean that I extend my main activity to ListActivity? If yes, then its id would be android:id="@android:id/list" ... and now I cannot access it to addHeaderView()

Comment: This isn't working. Its giving some layout params error now. I have same layout_height and width set for both the ImageView and ListView

Comment: Take the ImageView out of your layout XML. Whether you extend ListActivity or not is irrelevant. `addHeaderView()` is a method of ListView. If you extend ListActivity, you can use `getListView()`; otherwise you can get the ListView the same way you get other views.